# SQL Server Management Studio: prompt for user input

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

Is it possible in SQL Server Management Studio to ask the user for input and based on that input proceed?

I have a stored procedure which inserts some data into tables. When ever a user executes the stored procedure, I want a message to come up asking if he is sure he wants the stored procedure to execute.

If the response is Yes, then continue if No then terminate.

Comment: user input capturing is work of front end application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend writing a small application to handle this. I am not aware of any way to prompt the user for input when running sql. IMO Sql Management studio is not an environment for running scripts that require user input

Comment: There are situations where it would be helpful to run scripts which prompt for user input in SQL studio. For instance, I cam to this thread because I have a script which populates `SSISConfig` with connection details. Obviously things like `password` and `server` are different in Test and Prod. I would prefer to be prompted for those values rather than having to edit the script before running it.