# Show prompt from script in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ssms, prompt

I'm trying to create a prompt window while running a SQL script to ask the person who run the script to enter a value that it will be assigned to a variable.

How can I do it?

Comment: And which tool are you using for running the script?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: Related findings: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17960566/sql-server-management-studio-prompt-for-user-input & https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/272d1fdd-c0c9-4c60-a60e-8ebab0bec831/user-input-thru-ssms?forum=transactsql

Comment: I doubt SSMS is the right tool to do this. You can tell the user to change the variable value within the code, but other than that I'm not aware that it's possible. Generally, to my knowledge, this is not the environment to do that.

Comment: This would be simple to do with a bit of PowerShell and a sqlcmd script run with `Invoke-Sqlcmd`: `$tableName = Read-Host -Prompt "Table name"; Invoke-Sqlcmd -InputFile myscript.sql -Variable "TABLENAME='$tableName'"`.

Answer (score 2):

Prompting for user input is a job done in the client application/tool/utility. With SSMS, you could use a template script for this purpose (although that isn't is primary use case for templates). Below is an example template script.

```
DECLARE @UserValue varchar(10) = '<UserValue, varchar(10), default value>';
PRINT @UserValue;
GO
```

Press `SHIFT+CTRL+M` to prompt for template parameter values, press `OK`, and then execute the script.